# HTML Boostrap columns are not aligned properly

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to display a grid of pictures (4x3) using bootstrap in HTML. However, when I check the code the columns of pictures are there but they're not aligned properly. It looks like this:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/az2EC.png)

My code looks like this:

```
 <body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <br>
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-6"><h1><b>Storyboards</b></h1></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container"> <!--storyboard pages-->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <img src="lc01.jpeg"  alt="test">
            </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                <img src="lc02.jpeg"  alt="test">
            </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                <img src="lc03.jpeg"  alt="test">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <img src="lc04.jpeg"  alt="test">
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <img src="lc01.jpeg"  alt="test">
            </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                <img src="lc02.jpeg"  alt="test">
            </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                <img src="lc03.jpeg"  alt="test">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <img src="lc04.jpeg"  alt="test">
        </div>
</div>

<style>
img{
    width:280px;
    height:420px;
    border:1px solid #000000;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    }
```

```
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

If anyone could explain to me what mistake I'm making that would be very helpful. 
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't closing your last column in either row:

```
<div class="col-lg-3">
    <img src="lc04.jpeg"  alt="test">
```

Comment: I can't believe I missed that! When you look over the code countless times I guess you just get used to it, thanks for the quick reply

Answer (score -1):

Please check that you have missed the closing div for the rows ( or closing div for las column )

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
    </div>
</div>
```